# Fluent nHibernate - Wrong column name when self reference

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

The mapping on foreign key are made with the wrong name. Why?

Here's my classes:

**The order of the properties seems to be important**:

```
public class Person
{
  public virtual Person Mother { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
  public virtual Person Father { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the mapping with Fluent Nhibernate

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Person>(new CustomAutomappingConfiguration())
```

When I look to the database, the foreign key in the table seems to be the name of the first property with the type *Person* after the property *Items*. Here's the SQL generated to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Item" (Id  integer primary key autoincrement
    , Name TEXT
    , Father_id BIGINT
    , constraint FKC57C4A2B4586680 foreign key (Father_id) references Patient)
```

Thank you in advance for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found is to override the configuraton like this:

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Person>(new CustomAutomappingConfiguration())
    .Override<Person>(m => m.HasMany<Item>(x => x.Items).KeyColumn("Patient_Id"))
```

Does exist any solution to let the auto mapping work seamlessly? And how Fluent nHibernate works to choose the name of the foreign key's column?